# angular - filter throws error when filtered field is null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a little problem. When i am doing filtering on array if filtered field is null i always get error and rest of code after that fails. This is my code:

```
this.order= result.headerText.find((item) => item.textType === 'Order');
```

If i have texttype with 'Order' everything is fine, but if i have textType as null it throws error and rest of code is not executed.

[image]

How can i check if there is textType with Order and return it and when it is null it don't crash :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find() is a function belonging to array type. The error you get results from result.headerText being either null or NOT an array.

For instance you might consider checking like this:

```
if (result.headerText && Array.isArray(result.headerText)) {
    return result.headerText.find(item => item.textType === 'Order')
}

return undefined;
```

Comment: Hi Gregory. Thx for help. It is working, right now i can't test order with those fields populated, but when they are null i correctly skips that without breaking.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that an 'item' in the headerText is null but not textType

```
this.order = result.headerText && result.headerText.find((item) => item && item.textType === 'Order');
```

if you use the latest version of typescript you can use optional chaining proposal

```
this.order = result.headerText?.find((item) => item?.textType === 'Order');
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. When i try it i still get :ERROR TypeError: result.headerText.find is not a function in both solutions.

Comment: @user2565525 I understand headerText is not an array, I updated the solution above

Comment: Hi. I tried: let order= result.headerText && res.headerText.find((item) => item && item.textType === 'Order'); but still i am getting same error. What am i doing wrong? header text is aray with textType and textItem. When text type is not null everything works but null is killing me :). i tried with let order just to be sure that problem is not in this.order which is of type headerText

Comment: @user2565525 put a console.log before "this.order =  ..." when you receive an error and show what is displayed in the console

Comment: core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: result.headerText.find is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber._next (order-details.view.ts:73)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:27436)

Comment: @user2565525, The snippet which you shared above shows headerText is object, i am very much doubtful if it is holding an array value in your null case

Comment: Picture of header text rray is in my first post. When it holds null in both fields.

Comment: @user2565525 put this `console.log(result.headerText)` before assigning the value and show the output

Comment: hi i edited my original post to show snippet of the result.headerText

Comment: @user2565525, as I had mentioned it is an object and not an array. find() supports Array and not Object

Comment: @HemantHalwai and Chris thank you for your help. I used Gregory solution to skip find if i dont get array.